# Cannot read property 'params' of undefined with Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, parameters, undefined

I am trying to post some data of an object when i click on "show's button". So i want to keep its id. So i used this code in my container:

```
    import {connect} from "react-redux";
    import ShortcutCard from "./ShortcutCard";

    const mapStateToProps = (state,ownProps) => {
        let id = ownProps.match.params.id;
        return{
            shortcut : state.raccourcis.shortcuts.find(shortcut => shortcut.id ===id)
        }
    }
    const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({

    });

        export default connect(
          mapStateToProps,
          mapDispatchToProps
        )(ShortcutCard);
```

```
**and this one like a component(in an other file) :**
```

```
        import React, {Component} from 'react';
        import './ShortcutCard.scss';
        import {Link, Route} from "react-router-dom";

        class ShortcutCard extends Component {
          render() {
            const {shortcut} = this.props;

            return (
              <div className="col mb-4 cardContainer">
                <div className="card">
                  <div className="card-body">
                    <h2 className="card-title">{shortcut.title}</h2>
                    <p className="card-text">{shortcut.context}</p>
                    <img src={process.env.REACT_APP_UPLOADS_DIR + '/' + shortcut.software.logo} className="card-img-top" alt={shortcut.software.name}/>

                    <Link to={'/Excerpts/' + shortcut.id} >
                      <button>shows</button>
                    </Link>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            );
          }
        }

    export default ShortcutCard;
```

I dont know i got an error. "paramas undefined"

PS: i am a newbie on react and redux.

Comment: you don't show where you're using your connected `ShortcutCard` component, but it's obvious from the error message that you are failing to pass it a `match` prop. Either make sure you do that, or alter your `mapStateToProps` to account for the fact that it may be missing.

Comment: Oki so did i need to do something like <ShortcutCard/> in my component ShortcutCard? If yes i don't know where.

Comment: No. Wherever you currently render `ShortcutCard`, you need to pass it a prop called `match` (which further should be an object containing a key `params`, whose value is itself an object with a key called `id`). If any of the above is untrue at any point, you need to alter your `mapStateToProps` to guard against this. I can't tell you which is correct, as I know nothing about your application, and I can't even see where you're rendering `ShortcutCard`. I'm just going off what the error message, and your `mapStateToProps`, is clearly saying.

Comment: Oh i am using ShortcutCard in an other component. But i think i understand what you are saying, thanks. It s late. I will try tomorow to see that.